# Global status of the single schema in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to take up the global status of the single schema in mysql.

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

using the above query we can get the entire DB status. How can we do this for particular Schema for similar data.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: No. of transaction , Bytes sent and received for the single schema, no of failed transaction, no of queries fired for that particular schema. all the data we are getting from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS. the same needed for single schema

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

is a command for getting the status of server, not the schema.

> SHOW STATUS provides server status information.

Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-status.html) for more

Comment: Yes. But can i get the transaction (Like no.hits etc) related information of the particular schema.